# @font-face works with some fonts, but not all, even though they have the same extension

Tags: css, fonts

I call my fonts in my css this way.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mathilderegular';
    src: url('../font/mathilde/mathilde-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/mathilde/mathilde-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/mathilde/mathilde-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/mathilde/mathilde-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/mathilde/mathilde-webfont.svg#mathilderegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'microsoft_yi_baitiregular';
    src: url('../font/msyi/msyi-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/msyi/msyi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/msyi/msyi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/msyi/msyi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/msyi/msyi-webfont.svg#microsoft_yi_baitiregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face{
    font-family:'love';
    src: url('../font/love.ttf');
}
```

and assign it to a class:

```
.titel{font-family: 'mathilderegular';}
```

Everything works fine with the 'love' font, but the other fonts don't work. I called them before the same way as I did with the 'love' font, but that didn't work either.

I have my css in a css folder.

Anybody knows what's the problem here?

edit:
found the mathilde font on [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com)

generated with [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

html: `<span class="titel">Wie, Wat, Waar?</span>`

Comment: Have you checked if the paths are correct?

Comment: yes, double checked that.

Comment: You need to provide testable cases to make this question on-topic. This includes information about the sources of the fonts, how the font files were generated, and which exact HTML and CSS was used, and how you inferred that some fonts “don’t work” (presumably, aren’t used at all).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added an edit so hope this will clear up something. The not working thing for the first to fonts is that he shows a standard font in stead of the font I included and want to call..

Comment: Looking back in my questions I see I figured this out a while ago... When I download a webfont, sometimes the folder doesn't allow you to read the folder. Changing the rights solves this problem.